# Are there any repositories to find custom map tiles for an OpenLayers implementation?

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, wms, tiles

I can't seem to find an WMS that looks the way I want.  I've also checked all of the regular OSM places too and haven't quite found anything.
Can anyone recommend any places to find custom map tiles that I could use in my OpenLayers implementation?

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your question and provide more details as to what 'looks the way you want'

Comment: Well I'm looking for a simple tile set with geographical region boundaries and perhaps the region names.  But in general I just wasn't sure if I was missing some repository or easy way to find several options.

Comment: What regular places have you already checked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment,

if you are looking for a muted or minimalistic styled tile layer, have a look at [GeoIQ acetate](http://acetate.geoiq.com/tiles/acetate/preview.html).

Implement it like this:

```
acetate = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("Acetate","http://acetate.geoiq.com/tiles/acetate/${z}/${x}/${y}.png");
map.addLayer(acetate);
```

Comment: Thanks, this was exactly what I was looking for.  It still might be useful to me, though, to have a better idea of where to look for different tile sets that I could use in OpenLayers.